# Import text file data to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

Hello everyone i need help to import following text file data into MySQL database.

Here is one Sample Access log file:

123.123.123.123 - - [26/Apr/2000:00:23:48 -0400] "GET /pics/wpaper.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 6248 "http://www.jafsoft.com/asctortf/" "Mozilla/4.05 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"

123.123.123.123 - - [26/Apr/2000:00:23:51 -0400] "GET /cgi-bin/new-count?jafsof3&width=4&font=digital&nohow HTTP/1.0" 200 36 "http://www.jafsoft.com/asctortf/" "Mozilla/4.05 (Macintosh; I; PPC)"

I want to put this text data in MySQL database in row-column format.
What java code should i have to write.
Please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Outline your table schema and the mappings i.e what data you want to send to which column. This will greatly help in providing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer with the help of regular expression.